# Adding new tables to existing database does not work - EF Code First

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have an existing database that I first created using Ado.net and later transformed it into Code first using Ado.net Data Model wizard. I can retrieve the values from the database fine but I can't add new tables to the database.

for example, I have this table that I want to add to the Db:

```
    public class ChatUser
{
    public int ChatUserID { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public int ConversationID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ConversationID")]
    public Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
}
```

I added this in the DbContext class:

```
public virtual DbSet<ChatUser> ChatUsers { get; set; }
```

and then I ran these commands in the Package manager console:

```
Add-Migration Initial

Update-Database
```

Before updating the database, I deleted all the contents in Up() and Down() in the DbMigration class leaving just the contents of the new model as mentioned here : http://christesene.com/entity-framework-4-3-code-first-with-automatic-migrations/ but my database doesn't reflect these changed eventhough I can see the new migration stored in the Migration table in the database.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The tables from your earlier attempts will still exist in your database. You have two options:

- Reverse all the existing migrations, don't delete the content of the migration files
- Delete the database in your server and then run the `Add-migration` and `Update-database` commands again